# Opening a Microsoft Access database with PHP

Tags: php, ms-access

Okay need some help on opening an Access database with PHP. Below is the code that I am using to connect to the database and print out an array. I get this error "could not find driver Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object...

```
try{
    $dbh = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=sim.mdb;Uid=Admin");
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
} 

$stmt2 = $dbh->query ("SELECT * FROM Names");
    $array = $stmt2->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


print_r ($array);
```

Comment: It tells you that the driver is not installed. This rises the question: Did you install the driver correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to uncomment the following line in your php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

Comment: well I wouldnt know it seems my web hosting company has the AllowOverride set to no in the httpd.conf. So I can not even push a .htaccess file to change the php.ini file or create and post a php.ini. Any workarounds to get php to connect to the access database?

Comment: You could try: **<?php ini_set('extension', 'php_pdo_odbc.dll');  ?>** but I'm not sure if that will work with your current AllowOverride settings. The other option is to find a different host that allows you a little more control.

Comment: yeah this is solved but I think my solution is to convert the access database to sqlite